# Working remotely in U.K for a Japanese company - want to get mortgage

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, mortgage, foreign-income, japan

I have been living in Japan with my husband for the past 3 years.  We are both British. I work for an IT consulting firm with only a handful of staff where I am the only foreigner. I'll be turning 30 next year and I would like to start a family.  Since it's my first child, I'd really like to be at home in the UK, close to my Mum and MIL. I've spoken to my Boss and he's willing  to let me work remotely from the UK indefinitely.

I'd like to get a mortgage in the U.K with my husband. How do mortgage lenders validate overseas income and credibility? Can I work remotely from the U.K without paying taxes (N.I, etc?) if I'm already getting taxed here? If not, how does a Japanese company go about this? I'd like to qualify for a mortgage and I'm not sure what the best procedure course of action is due to my salary which essentially will become foreign income.

Comment: Welcome to personal finance. It would help if you split this into 2 distinct questions. One: How can you get mortgage in UK, if your jobs are in Japan. Second: Tax implications for you if you work for a Japanese company from UK. Please add details about how this job is being structured; i.e. will you still be full time employee of Japanese entity? or you will be a freelance consultant and getting paid etc. Likely date when you will be in UK to determine your tax residency.

Comment: Yes you're right, it definitely should be in two questions, sorry about that.

I will be a full-time employee of Japanese entity, being paid into my Japanese bank account, in Yen. I am hoping to come back to the U.K November 2019.
Thank you for your fast reply.

Comment: Go through this, which might help regarding paying NI in UK or not.  https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income You won't pay tax twice because of double taxation treaty between UK and Japan. For tax advise I would get in touch with an accountant dealing in UK & Japan taxes, but that is if your situation is quite complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You pay the taxes  in the UK. Your boss would probably tax the payments already in Japan but if you also make a tax report there, you should get it back. Some social payment could stay in Japan.

About the credit in England, if you show them your last 2-3 months of income, last year's tax report, and maybe a letter from your boss that you would continue to work remotely (in English) then it shouldn't be a problem. You'll probably need to pay an official translator so the bank can understand the reports that they are valuating.